# IIS virtual directory from web.config

Tags: iis, web-config, virtual-directory

I have a IIS problem that I think [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20201127004607/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37609.aspx) gives me a fix for:

> To resolve it, Right Click on the virtual directory - select properties and then click on "Create" next to the "Application" Label and the textbox. It will
> automatically create the "application" using the virtual directory's name. Now the application can be accessed.

However I don't have access to the IIS GUI. Is there a way to do the same thing by editing the web.config file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. Configuring a directory as an application, setting up the AppPool, etc is the responsibility of the web server. Typically your web hosting provider will offer a control panel that lets you configure the virtual directories. If not, you'll need to contact them through their support channels to have this done.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create a virtual directory via your web.config.   If this is on a web host then you will need to use whatever user interface they give you to create Virtual Directories.

Answer (score 0):

or on some hosted sites that you're allowed access to, you need to put in a ticket to the service center or help desk to get them make it an app.  They will need to know which version of the .net framework you want it to be also.

Comment: In IIS Advance Setting -> Application Pool is "DefaultAppPool" and use .Net Framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageResizer` project has a way to create a virtual folder using its own mechanism. It isn't recommended for production, but it may suit some needs.

Add

```
<add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/" physicalPath="..\Images" vpp="false "/>
```

to the `<plugins />` section.

http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/virtualfolder

Comment: Does not work with `MapPath` (because it's not really a virtual directory) so if you need that to work this is no good